# javac can't understand classpath behaviour

Tags: java, compilation, classpath, javac

I am trying to compile the basic MapReduce Wordcount example using the following command:

```
javac -classpath /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar  -d wordcount_classes/ WordCount.java
```

This throws the following error:

```
javac: invalid flag: :/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

But when I list in a sort of piece wise manner ie. by first specifying the 
`commons` jar file

```
javac -classpath /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.3.jar -d wordcount_classes/ WordCount.java
```

It shows regular compilation error with the code ie.

```
WordCount.java:9: error: package org.apache.hadoop.mapred does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
^
WordCount.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
                                    ^
  symbol:   class MapReduceBase
  location: class WordCount
WordCount.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
                                                             ^
  symbol:   class Mapper
  location: class WordCount
WordCount.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
                                                  ^
  symbol:   class OutputCollector
  location: class Map
WordCount.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

....(more errors then finally -->) 16 errors found
```

And when I follow this with the original huge classpath command, my program compiles without errors. Can someone please tell me why this happens and how I can compile the file in one go using the multiple classpath line instead of having to resort to this piece wise approach?

Comment: You have to ensure that the shell doesn’t do name expansion before launching `javac`.